# Cannot set paths in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, cygwin, pythonpath

I am trying to set up a simple library in Python using a mintty window running tcsh (don't ask!) in Cygwin but cannot get it to work.

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\pypath1\;C:\pypath2\
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

gives me a huge list of directories - some of which appear to be "corrupted". eg:

```
'/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Documents/ ...... /scripts/C'          
'/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Documents/ ...... /scripts/\\cygwin\\bin;C',
```

The first one doesn't exist and the second appears to have been concatenated with something else.
In addition, the two dummy directories I added to PYTHONPATH do not appear.
I have been fiddling with things (editing PYTHONPATH via Windows and in csh.login) and appear to have stuffed something up.

How can I get rid of the spurious entries and then actually start adding the directories I want/need?!

Newbie post so be gentle!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Is there a specific reason you are trying to use a non-Cygwin Python? And what do you mean by "set up a simple library"?

Comment: I want to set up a path to a library so I can easily access from anywhere without having to specify the path in each single script.  
Not sure re you question about "non-cygwin Python". When I type "which python"  get "/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/python".

Comment: That's weird.  `which python` should just return `/usr/bin/python` or `/bin/python`.  It shouldn't be returning the full `/cygdrive/c` path.  It sounds like you have your `$PATH` messed up too.  Also in `tcsh`, `set` sets internal shell variables; you need `setenv` to set an environment variable.  Is this your own Python code?

Comment: OK I tried:
`setenv PYTHONPATH "C:\pypath1\;C:\pypath2"`
This gave weird paths such as:
`/cygdrive/c/Users/User/........./PLOT_dir/\pypath2`
The python code is a simple one line as indicated.

Comment: How exactly did you install Python?  What does it show when you run `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'`?  Let's make sure you're even using the correct Python and that your environment is set up correctly before worrying about PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I have installed python several times from different sources. One from Anaconda because I needed the matplot site-package. It appears this is now the one I am running. `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'` gives `3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:23:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: Note that I have been fiddling since my earlier reply (trying to fix things but probably making things worse!) because then it appeared I was using "/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/python". Maybe just need to start again with fresh installs?